# a more common occurrence than any one would think who only knew me through your memoirs

Tags: ambiguity

Quote:

“Because I made a blunder, my dear Watson—which is, I am afraid, a more common occurrence than any one would think who only knew me through your memoirs. The fact is that I could not believe it possible that the most remarkable horse in England could long remain concealed, especially in so sparsely inhabited a place as the north of Dartmoor. From hour to hour yesterday I expected to hear that he had been found, and that his abductor was the murderer of John Straker. When, however, another morning had come, and I found that beyond the arrest of young Fitzroy Simpson nothing had been done, I felt that it was time for me to take action. Yet in some ways I feel that yesterday has not been wasted.”

Question：

"A more common occurence than any one would think" means:

A. something more common than everyone thought happened

or

B. something very rare happened

According to the context i guess the answer should be B. But i do feel confused with such expression.

Comment: Anyone who doesn't know Sherlock Holmes, but has read what Dr Watson has written about him, would think that he never makes a mistake. In fact, Holmes says, it's quite common for him to make a mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The sentence with the most prepositions at its end -- does it really work?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20417/the-sentence-with-the-most-prepositions-at-its-end-does-it-really-work) This is about postposition of relative clauses.

Comment: Also covered at [Delayed relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208849/delayed-relative-clause). 'In this chapter, the fundamental physiological principles will be presented that underlie the mathematical models and simulations of the subsequent chapters.' But [Position of a relative clause before/after a verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105776/position-of-a-relative-clause-before-after-a-verb) is the one I've been looking for. 'Extraposition from NP.'

Comment: This is an example of the rule of [Extraposition from NP](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105786/15299), which moves a heavy clause from an internal position to the end of the sentence, where it's easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is because "any one" is modified by a phrase that comes after "would think." The syntax could be rearranged:

> [My blunders are] a more common occurrence than *any one who only knew me through your memoirs* would think.

Regarding your proposed paraphrases, this means "something happened that people think is very rare, but is more common than they think."